# dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli falied

Tags: flutter

dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
Package flutterfire_cli is currently active at version 0.2.7.
Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 2.12.2.

Because flutterfire_cli >=0.3.0-dev.13 depends on xml ^6.1.0 and flutterfire_cli >=0.3.0-dev.0 <0.3.0-dev.13 depends on xml ^5.3.1, flutterfire_cli

> =0.3.0-dev.0 requires xml ^5.3.1 or ^6.1.0.
> And because flutterfire_cli <=0.2.5-dev.0 depends on xml ^5.3.1 and flutterfire_cli >=0.2.5 <0.3.0-dev.0 depends on xml ^6.1.0, every version of
> flutterfire_cli requires xml >=5.3.1 <6.0.0 or >=6.1.0 <7.0.0.
> So, because xml >=5.2.0 requires SDK version >=2.13.0 <3.0.0 or >=3.0.0 <4.0.0 and pub global activate depends on flutterfire_cli any, version solving
> failed.

i had problem to lunch firebase in flutter